# Derived Categories - Class of quasi-isomorphism

Tags: derived-categories

I was studying model categories, in particular the model structure of the category $Ch(A)$ of chain complexes of an abelian category A and I saw that some authors define $D(A)=HoCh(A)$ as being the localisation in the quasi -isomorphisms instead of saying that $D(A)$ is the localisation in the quasi-ismorphisms in $K(A)$ the category of  complexes  modulo homotopy equivalence. My question is, why do some authors say that the class of all quasi-isomorphisms does not form a localization class and others do?

Comment: The difference between the two categories is that $Q^{-1}\mathbf{Ch}(A)$ is not an Ore localization (in the sense that it is only a localization of categories) while $Q^{-1}K(A)$ is an Ore localization (in the sense that it is induced by a, two-sided in this case, calculus of fractions). Note that I explicitly mean that $\mathbf{Ch}(A) \to Q^{-1}\mathbf{Ch}(A)$ is not an Ore localization but $K(A) \to Q^{-1}K(A)$ is an Ore localization; in either case here we also have $Q$ as the class of quasi-isomorphisms in each respective category.

Comment: so saying that $D(A)=Q^{-1}Ch(A)$ is wrong? I think Quillen says this and I see it in several other articles too.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's wrong, as both categories are isomorphic (they both have the universal property that they are localizations of $\mathbf{Ch}(A)$ at quasi-isomorphisms) but just that which definition you use should reflect what you're doing and where you're working. For what it's worth, in practice I tend to use $D(A) = \mathbf{Ch}(A)$ as a working definition and if I ever need to have nice factorization properties of morphisms I work in $Q^{-1}K(A)$ and keep track carefully of my comparison functors.

Comment: Ooh now I get it, it makes sense. Thank you very much.